# How call C function in js with render SDL in canvas

Tags: html, c, sdl, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to render in canvas the module that I built with SDL2, but I also need to call functions while the module is running and send data there, according to the examples I found it turns out so:

```js
   var Module = {
         canvas: (function () {
             var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
             canvas.addEventListener('webglcontextlost', e => {
                 alert('WebGL context lost. You will need to reload the page.');
                 e.preventDefault();
             }, false);
             return canvas;
         })(),

     };

     SSE.onmessage = msg => {
         Module.onRuntimeInitialized = () => {
             Module.ccall('set_num', null, ['number'], [msg]);
        };
     }
```

The function was called once, but I need to call it constantly in the event

make with

```
override CFLAGS += -std=c11\
                -Os\
                -sUSE_SDL_TTF=2\
                -sUSE_SDL_IMAGE=2\
                -sSDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS=["png"]\
                -sEXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap']\
                -sUSE_SDL=2\
                -sWASM=1\
                -sASSERTIONS\
                --preload-file ./res
```

C

```c
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
#endif
void set_num(int num) { g_obj->num = num; }
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with JS calling C and wasm, but, in normal C compiler invocation, `-s` is to strip the output of symbols. With (e.g.) `-sUSE_SDL_TTF=2` are you trying to define C preprocessor macros? If so, you might want: `-DUSE_SDL_TTF=2` instead. This change would work for some/most of the definitions, but `-sEXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap']` seems problematic. Are you trying to define an _array_? This seems like JS syntax, but it wouldn't be valid for C. We'd need to see more of your C code.

Comment: These are the flags of the emcc compiler